# Why is the phase margin more important than the gain margin?

Tags: control-system, stability, phase-margin

I heard from some lecturers that the phase margin is more important than the gain margin. However, after searching online and in some control related textbooks I couldn't find any reference for such claim. There is only one example related from DC-DC converters [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/371549/why-is-phase-margin-considered-more-important-than-gain-margin-in-dc-dc-converte#:%7E:text=6-,Why%20is%20phase%20margin%20considered%20more%20important,margin%20in%20dc%2Ddc%20converters%3F&text=Control%20theory%20text%20books%20say,closed%20loop%20system%27s%20transient%20response.).

Is the above claim true in general? Is there any reference to support or reject the claim?

Comment: IMO really they are both important, but one way of looking at the stability criterion may be easier to grasp than the other.

Comment: @user_1818839 my lecturer told me that in practice, engineers care more about the phase margin than the gain margin. But I don't understand why?

Comment: "care more about" is not the same as "is more important". Answers to your linked question look pretty good to me, especially the accepted one. You might explain what specifically is unclear to you about them.

Answer (score 2):

When we design an amplifier with negative feedback, we will be interested in how the phase angle changes from DC up to when the high-frequency gain is unity. So, at DC the phase angle may be very close to 180° and offer perfect negative feedback. As frequency rises that phase angle will deteriorate towards 0° but, if it hasn't reached 0° by the time the gain has dropped below unity we know that the circuit is unlikely to turn into an oscillator at higher frequencies because the gain is likely to remain below unity at any higher frequency.

So, if we **only** know the phase margin (the number of degrees the phase angle is distant from 0° at unity gain), we can say with a fair degree of confidence that the circuit is unlikely to oscillate. We can also be fairly confident about the transient overshoot we might see for a step change in the input.

However, if we **only** know the gain margin, things are less clear. Gain margin might tell us (for a typical design) that the gain is a lot less than unity when the phase angle crosses through 0° (what we want) but, we would still require an extra calculation to know what the phase margin might be because, we'd like to understand about transient overshoots (as mentioned above).

That extra calculation can be made assuming that the roll-off of open loop gain is 20 dB/decade (common for a lot of op-amps for instance) but, it doesn't guarantee that for every circuit and every op-amp chosen that the phase margin isn't very close to 0° at unity gain.

So, in my personal opinion, I would rather know phase margin because it tells me two things and those two things are more likely to be "reliable" compared to working backwards from gain margin.

Comment: +1 Completely agree-  One additional point is that the gain can vary due to component tolerances.  Some integrated gm amplifiers for example have +/- 30% tolerances.  So in some systems the gain margin can tell you how likely you are to get into trouble as the gain varies from system to system or over temperature.

Answer (score 0):

In a minimum phase system (which is many, but not all, simple amplifier / filter systems) the phase and gain are related by the Hilbert criterion, which means that in theory you could get the same information from either.

In practice, when you create a Bode plot, the phase plot is somewhat more sensitive, and so easier to interpret in terms of what you have to do to stabilise the system, than the gain plot.

In a non-minimum phase system, there is not that relation. For instance an all pass filter is deployed specifically to alter the phase without changing the amplitude at all.

In all systems, you need to have an adequate margin for both gain and phase.